# How to install SQL Developer on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, oracle, sql

I am trying to install SQL Developer on Ubuntu 14.04. I have followed some tutorials but none of them worked. So I am asking you if you know how to install SQL Developer.

Comment: I have the same question!

Comment: Finally, I can install SQL Developer. See my answer.

Comment: _What_ tutorials? _How_ did they "not work"? Please show us what you did and what the result is.

Comment: This one worked for me: http://oracle-noob.blogspot.com/2014/01/install-oracle-sql-developer-40-in.html

Comment: when I am trying to perform last step i.e., run sqldeveloper below error gk@gk-desktop:/usr/local/bin$ ./sqldeveloper
./sqldeveloper: line 3: ./sqldeveloper: Permission denied Any solution to over come?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I installed SQL Developer with these steps:

1. *(See the comments—this might not be necessary)*
   Download and re-install newest Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from Ubuntu website.
2. Install Java:

   - Java Version JDK 7:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre icedtea-7-plugin
     sudo update-alternatives --config java
     ```
   - Java Version JDK 8 (in some installations this is a requirement instead of 1.7):

     ```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
     sudo update-alternatives --config java
     ```
3. [Download SQL Developer from Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) (I chose **Other Platforms** download).
4. Extract file to `/opt`:

   ```
   sudo unzip sqldeveloper-*-no-jre.zip -d /opt/
   sudo chmod +x /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
   ```
5. Linking over an in-path launcher for Oracle SQL Developer:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper
   ```
6. Edit `/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh` and replace it's content to:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   unset -v GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
   cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
   ./sqldeveloper "$@"
   ```

   or (to prevent error: `./sqldeveloper: Permission denied`)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   unset -v GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
   cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $*
   ```
7. Run SQL Developer:

   ```
   sqldeveloper
   ```

   > Note: When you run Sql Developer at the first time, you need to
   >   specify the path of JDK's folder. In my computer, JDK stored at
   >   **/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64**
   >   For Java 8 and Ubuntu 16+ **/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle**
8. Finally, create desktop application for easy to use:

   ```
   cd /usr/share/applications/
   sudo vim sqldeveloper.desktop
   ```

   add this lines:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Exec=sqldeveloper
   Terminal=false
   StartupNotify=true
   Categories=GNOME;Oracle;
   Type=Application
   Icon=/opt/sqldeveloper/icon.png
   Name=Oracle SQL Developer
   ```

   then type:

   ```
   sudo update-desktop-database
   ```

Comment: "Download and re-install newest Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from Ubuntu website" why do I need to remove my operating system to install a package?

Comment: I've compacted this down a bit, improved formatting and and pushed a few fixes. Like the others I'm not sure 14.04 is really required for this so I put a notice in there.

Comment: I don't know why but I can't install any software (java,alien,...) from the version release in April 17. In fact, i may made many things that crashed my OS and re-installed is necessary to me. :)

Comment: @PhatHV When i run sqldeveloper in terminal I get /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper: line 2: cd: /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper/bin: Not a directory

Comment: did you complete the step 6 above?

Comment: @PhatHV all of them. I have managed to install sql developer, but i have used other tutorial.

Comment: I tried many other tutorial like you. But I gave you what steps I did to make my SQL Developer works (I installed it on my machine at office and it works perfect until now). I thinks you should check the content of this file "/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh" and paste it here.

Comment: I don't like creating /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper.sh, I prefer to create sqldeveloper.desktop and launch for Unity bar. See my answer to other question: http://askubuntu.com/a/487026/12064

Comment: I think that maybe step 6 should be `/usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper` instead of `/usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper.sh`? In any case, I'm having the same problem @vladmateinfo, and I've tried it three times now.

Comment: All works but for somereason my whole sqldevloper foler and it's files and only readable for users that are non sudoers. Even if I do sudo chmod -R 775 on it, nothing changes. This makes me unable to use the desktop shortcut as I have to give sudo right always

Comment: Step 6 have two options. First option was contributed by the community, the second one is true config on my machine.

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 15.04, using java 8 instead of java 7.

Comment: excellent solution, but check what version of java oracle requests at sqldeveloper download page from step 3 before proceeding and use that version of java when doing step 2

Comment: The download lead me to an rpm package which was install simply by using alien.

Comment: Is there any other way to download sql developer without creating account?

Comment: FYI, a better icon file can be found at `/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/SQLDeveloperIcons.icns`. It's the macOS icons file and it will scale with the size of the icon, plus it doesn't have the white background.

Comment: @PhatHV you're my hero

Comment: I got an "java.langUnsatisfiedLinkError" pop up when I ran the sqldeveloper commad. I used this command to fix it: sudo apt-get install libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386
Taken from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/674579/libawt-xawt-so-libxext-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: @PhatHV Works like a charm on Ubuntu 18.04 and Open JDK 11

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, I found that I was unable to install Java by the method described because the PPA is not available. Instead, I did `sudo apt install default-jre` and `sudo apt install default-jdk` These installs gave me OpenJDK 11.0.8 as of September 9, 2020. I did NOT need to tell Oracle SQL Developer the location of my JDK.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I did it on Ubuntu, I think this is the easiest way and will give you a package that you can easily reuse later (but you can't redistribute according to OTN license):

1. Downlod the sql developer package from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).
2. Install the sql developer package as the following.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sqldeveloper-package debhelper openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre icedtea-7-plugin
   ```
3. Now all what you need to do is to run the command (you might have a different version)

   ```
   make-sqldeveloper-package sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-no-jre.zip
   ```
4. This will generate a debian package that you can use to install sql developer.
5. Now install the resulting .deb package using the command (Your deb might have a different version too):

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i sqldeveloper_4.1.3.20.78+0.2.4-1_all.deb
   ```
6. You're now done with the installation. in my case it needed the new java 8 then you will need to run the following commands.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
   ```
7. Finally you need to provide the java path for oracle sql developer at the first run in my case it was at `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/`.

Comment: Please note on Ubuntu the latest version of `sqldeveloper-package` is broken; failing with `debuild: fatal error at line 1124:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc binary failed` This can be fixed with `sudo sed -i '/DEBUILD/s/n b/n --no-tgz-check -- b/' /usr/bin/make-sqldeveloper-package`

Answer (score 6):

I installed version 17.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME like so.

1. Verify installation of OpenJDK 8 and location at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` If absent, install with `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`. Newer versions of Java may work as well.
2. Accept license agreement and download ["Other Platforms" version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)
3. Unzip in my home directory
4. Run from the commandline `~/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh` once to add location of Java. Enter `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`
5. Create the desktop icon for future access from my GUI menu.

   ```
   # /home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/sqldeveloper.desktop
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Oracle SQL Developer
   GenericName=SQL Developer
   X-GNOME-FullName=Oracle SQL Developer
   Comment= A free integrated development environment that simplifies the development and management of Oracle Database
   Keywords=sql;developer;oracle;db;database
   Exec=/home/USERNAME/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   Icon=/home/USERNAME/sqldeveloper/icon.png
   Categories=Admin
   X-AppStream-Ignore=true
   ```

Make the desktop file executable

```
chmod +x /home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/sqldeveloper.desktop
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Install Java 6. (It didn't work for me with Java 1.7):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
   ```
2. Download the SQL Developer from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) and choose *Other platforms*. (You'll need an account in order to download it). Open the Downloads directory:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```

   and extract the file to `/opt`:

   ```
   sudo unzip sqldeveloper-*-no-jre.zip -d /opt/
   ```
3. Make the launch script executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
   ```
4. Open sqldeveloper:

   ```
   sudo /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
   ```

   The first time you'll be asked to enter the jvm location. In my case (and probably yours if you have followed the first step), the location is: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle` .

Comment: Is this working for you? or did you install Sql developer from following your accepted answer or your own answer? because I want to install Sql developer for myself. thanks

Comment: @KasiyA This worked for me.

Comment: Instead of the 4. step, you can add the /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin to the PATH in the /etc/environment. Then you can use the sqldeveloper command from the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

I installed oracle sqldeveloper in ubuntu 17.10 using the following method:

1. Accept license agreement and download oracle linux rpm: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html
2. Install alien:

   sudo apt-get install alien
3. Install the rpm using alien:

   sudo alien -i sqldeveloper-17.3.1.279.0537-1.noarch.rpm
4. Run sql developer by using the following command in the terminal

   sqldeveloper

Make sure to change the version of your rpm. 
For this to be successful you have to have oracle java 8 or above installed in your machine.

Comment: Thank you so much bro.