# Unable to install Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.2 (4.0.2.15.21) from rpm file

Tags: software-installation, oracle, rpm

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 (using Update Manager), and it works fine with no issues.

In which I am using SQL Developer 3.2.20.09 and it works fine. Now a newer version was released on May 5th 2014, and I would like to use it, as it works fine with JDK 1.7.
I followed the installation instructions provided by Oracle, but it fails to install.

1. Downloaded sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-1.noarch.rpm from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html
2. Followed installation instructions from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-install-linux-1969676.html using the command:

   ```
   rpm -Uhv sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-1.noarch.rpm
   ```

   which resulted in:

   ```
   rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
   rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
   error: Failed dependencies:
       /bin/sh is needed by sqldeveloper-4.0.1.14.48-1.noarch
   ```
3. Used Alien to install the RPM package:

   ```
   sudo alien sqldeveloper-4.0.1.14.48-1.noarch.rpm
   ```

   which resulted in this error:

   ```
   error: db5 error(-30969) from dbenv->open: BDB0091 DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch
   error: cannot open Packages index using db5 -  (-30969)
   error: cannot open Packages database in /home/arthanarisamy/.rpmdb
   ```

Should any package be updated manually, or have I missed updating while upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using the RPM instead of the "other platforms" I use SQL Developer but I have always installed it using this method. www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/otherplatform-installnotes-1719935.html

Comment: No, there is no specific reason for using it, i tried to download Linux version and its installation notes.

Comment: Also i can give a try with other platforms as well, will let you know in some time about it.

Comment: Using other platform downloads and zip file worked, but had to modify sqldeveloper.sh file as below 

     #!/bin/bash
     unset -v GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
     cd "`dirname $0`"/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $*

Answer (score 2):

You should first convert .rpm file to .deb which is the installation file format in ubuntu.

```
sudo alien -d sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-1.noarch.rpm
```

Then install that .deb file by :

```
sudo dpkg -i sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-1.noarch.deb
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this solution and update. I was missing -d while executing alien command.

Comment: `sudo alien -k --scripts sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-1.noarch.rpm` works too

Answer (score 1):

I don't like using converted RPM for installation in Ubuntu, if there is an alternative.

I prefer manually using a binary package, specially with Java applications that usually does not have specific dependency (obviously JRE / JDK).

In this case, I install SQLDeveloper in this way:

- download the "**Other Platforms**" package: **sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre.zip**
- unzip the package in /opt/sqldeveloper (or other directory if you like, I put all manually installed packages in /opt)
- create a [sqldeveloper.desktop](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7689094/) file in /usr/share/applications (for all users) or ~/.local/share/applications (for your user only)

Comment: Please make a link for _sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre.zip_

Answer (score 0):

For me while rpm was not installed when I double click on the document it extracts it and I was able to run sqldeveloper by running /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh bash file

Answer (score -1):

The `error: db5 error(-30969) from dbenv->open: BDB0091 DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch` error happens the first time you run `rpm` (or `alien`) on Ubuntu.

Create the RPM DB with:

```
sudo rpm --rebuilddb
```

to get rid of it.