# SQL Developer runs in Terminal with sudo sqldeveloper but not without sudo

Tags: sqldeveloper

Can anyone help?
Installed like here:

[How to install SQL Developer on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458554/how-to-install-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-14-04)

If I run:

```
sudo sqldeveloper
```

it starts and runs properly but if I run:

```
sqldeveloper
```

It wont start with any other error shown.

Are there missing rights for Sqldeveloper or Java. Where and how do I set them.

Any help appreciated, I am a Ubuntu noob.

Where do I find error logs?

Thank you...

Comment: Do you have a (hidden) `"$HOME/.sqldeveloper"` directory? if so, what are its ownership and permissions?

Comment: yes it is hidden:
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      root      4096 Dez 29 15:00 .sqldeveloper

Comment: thank you sudo changemod 777 .sqldeveloper worked
although do not really understand what this directory is for and why it is not set properly

Comment: You should have changed the ownership not the permission bits - please see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

Likely what happened is you ran `sqldeveloper` one time using `sudo`, which caused the configuration directory `$HOME/.sqldeveloper` to get owned by root. If so, you should be able to fix it by re-taking ownership of the directory, i.e.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.sqldeveloper
```

or by simply deleting the directory

```
rm -rf ~/.sqldeveloper
```

Comment: This should be `chown`, not `chmod`

Answer (score 0):

If we need to run sqldeveloper without sudo we need to run command in terminal

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.sqldeveloper
```