# Unable to install SQL

Tags: software-installation, sql

I am new to UNIX, Linux and Ubuntu ... 
I am unable to install SQL on my system

I follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458554/how-to-install-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Error After Installation

```
Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /home/joelj/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf
```

Can someone help ?????

Answer (score 0):

You need to type in the path of your JDK / OpenJDK installation, to see in which path JDK / OpenJDK  is installed in you can run this command in a Terminal:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```