# libawt_xawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1842)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.(Toolkit.java:1668)
    at java.awt.Component.(Component.java:593)
    at EventTest.(EventTest.java:28)
    at EventTest.main(EventTest.java:49)
```

Answer (score 19):

```
apt-get install libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386
```

helped me get this resolved.

I have installed in a 64 bit system also i386.

Comment: This worked for me where the other answers would not.  Thanks.

Comment: For sure this is correct answer if you're running i386 version of JRE or any other software which depends on this set of libs. You always must match architecture between runtime and shared libs.

Comment: I had to launch 'sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386' command then 'sudo apt-get update' before to be able to install i386 versions of libraries

Answer (score 17):

Check which package contains the file and install it:

```
$ apt-file search libXext.so.6 
libxext6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 
libxext6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
libxext6-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
```

So install `libxext6`:

```
sudo apt install libxext6
```

Comment: sir this method is not working

Comment: What part? The apt-file or apt install?

Comment: sir i mean above mentioned error is not rectify by this method

Comment: So, is the file actually there? sudo find / -name 'libXext*'

Comment: Could very well be a version conflict in 32-bit vs. 64-bit. Please check out this question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543014/shared-libraries-java-32-bit-on-64bit-ubuntu

Comment: For me on Windows WSL `sudo updatedb` was required after installing `libxtst6`. Source: http://imadethisdesign.blogspot.com/2014/07/64-bit-linux-libxiso6-and-libxtstso6.html

Answer (score 16):

I had to install this (on ubuntu 16.04 64 bit) to make oracle-jdk8 work:

```
sudo apt-get install libxrender1 libxtst6 libxi6
```

Comment: I do not know what, but this fixed my problems after trying hundreds of other apt install whatever commands from other answers!