# Install Oracle Java 6 error issue

Tags: software-installation, java, oracle

I'm trying to install oracle-java6-installer on Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed it with these steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

but I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-core 
ttf-kochi-gothic | ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho | ttf- 
sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
The following NEW packages will be installed:
oracle-java6-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/21.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 209 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java6-installer.
(Reading database ... 215570 files and directories currently 
installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java6-installer_6u45- 
0~webupd8~8_all.deb ...
oracle-license-v1-1 license has already been accepted
Unpacking oracle-java6-installer (6u45-0~webupd8~8) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209- 
0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up oracle-java6-installer (6u45-0~webupd8~8) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 6...
--2018-04-19 09:46:17--  http://download.oracle.com/otn- 
pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.53.64.147
Connecting to download.oracle.com 
(download.oracle.com)|23.53.64.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk- 
6u45-linux-x64.bin [following]
--2018-04-19 09:46:17--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn- 
pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 
104.116.18.92, 2600:1417:1b:184::2d3e, 2600:1417:1b:188::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com 
(edelivery.oracle.com)|104.116.18.92|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk- 
6u45-linux-x64.bin? 
AuthParam=1524102497_fa8d9de89ff9d81e73b656b883c0b633 [following]
--2018-04-19 09:46:17--  http://download.oracle.com/otn- 
pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin? 
AuthParam=1524102497_fa8d9de89ff9d81e73b656b883c0b633
Connecting to download.oracle.com 
(download.oracle.com)|23.53.64.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-04-19 09:46:18 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 6 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java6-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
oracle-java6-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

openjdk-6-jdk has no installation candidate in Ubuntu 16.04 and later. Instead it is recommended to install openjdk-8-jdk from the terminal with the command:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Java 6 is still available at the [Java SE 6 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) webpage of the official Oracle website. Select the .tar.gz file which is currently named jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin (for 64-bit architecture) or jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin (for 32-bit  architecture). Oracle gives this warning that the packages in the Oracle Java Archive packages are no longer updated with the latest security patches.

> These older versions of the JRE and JDK are provided to help developers debug issues in older systems. They are not updated with the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production.

---

### Java 6 Installation

> 1. Download the jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin file. If you have a 32-bit Ubuntu installation, download jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin instead.
> 2. Make the downloaded bin file executable.
>
>    ```
>    chmod +x jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
>    ```
> 3. Extract the bin file.
>
>    ```
>    ./jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
>    ```
> 4. Using the following command create a folder called "jvm" inside `/usr/lib` if it does not already exist.
>
>    ```
>    sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
>    ```
> 5. Move the extracted folder into the newly created jvm folder.
>
>    ```
>    sudo mv jdk1.6.0_45 /usr/lib/jvm/
>    ```
> 6. To install the Java source run the following commands.
>
>    ```
>    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javac 1  
>    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java 1  
>    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javaws 1
>    ```
> 7. To make this default java:
>
>    ```
>    sudo update-alternatives --config javac    
>    sudo update-alternatives --config java    
>    sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
>    ```
> 8. To make symlinks point to the new Java location run the following command.
>
>    ```
>     ls -la /etc/alternatives/java*
>    ```
> 9. To verify Java has installed correctly run this command.
>
>    ```
>    java -version
>    ```

<sub>**Revised from:** [Installing Oracle Java 6 on Ubuntu](https://web.archive.org/web/20190712015635/https://dzone.com/articles/installing-oracle-java6-ubuntu)</sub>

Comment: Please note https://askubuntu.com/questions/674579/libawt-xawt-so-libxext-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di as a followup issue

Answer (score 2):

Java 6 is no longer supported by Oracle (some updates are still available through Java SE Support program, but that's not available publicly - from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6)). Install Java 8 or newer instead.