# Oracle SQLDeveloper "no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path"

Tags: 16.04, oracle, sqldeveloper

I am trying to get Oracle SQL Developer to work in 16.04. I followed PhatHV's answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458554/how-to-install-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-14-04) question, and the desktop app opens fine and appears correct, but when I try to connect to a database (and I know this should work because I've connected to the same database in Windows), an error window pops up saying

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path

Vendor code 0
```

Does anyone know what causes this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For me it only works when I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to the Instant Client directory, doing so in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf and running `sudo ldconfig` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have now managed (with some help) to fix this problem on two separate computers, but it's been long enough that I don't remember everything we did to fix it. I'll include at least what I remember, and may amend this answer later on. I don't understand everything under the hood, so I apologize if there are unnecessary steps. However, as I mentioned in the original question, I had followed another answer given by PhatHV, and I will not repeat here the steps found there. It is assumed that you have followed his tutorial before coming here.

## Install the Oracle Instant Client

For SQL Developer version 4.2.0 I needed to get version 12.2.0.1.0 of the Instant Client. You can find the download [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html). Select the "Instant Client for Linux" that corresponds to your architecture (I have a 64 bit machine, so I opened the x86-64 option. Download the following 5 files (substituting version number and architecture where appropriate):

- oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86-64.rpm
- oracle-instantclient12.2-devel-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86-64.rpm
- oracle-instantclient12.2-jdbc-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86-64.rpm
- oracle-instantclient12.2-odbc-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86-64.rpm
- oracle-instantclient12.2-sqlplus-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86-64.rpm

If you don't have it already, you will need to install a tool called `alien`:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

Navigate to your Downloads directory (or wherever you saved the files), and run `sudo alien -i` on each file to install it. We use `alien` becaues it first converts them to `.deb` before installing them. As a note, `alien` doesn't produce much output right away, so it may look like it's not doing anything, but I promise it is.

```
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86-64.rpm
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient12.2-devel-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86-64.rpm
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient12.2-jdbc-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86-64.rpm
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient12.2-odbc-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86-64.rpm
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient12.2-sqlplus-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86-64.rpm
```

## Edit Profile and Environment Variables

You will need to be a root user for all of these commands. Run `sudo su` to login as root.

Edit `/etc/profile.d/oracle.sh` to contain the following:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
export TNS_ADMIN=/usr/lib/oracle/ora
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

Note here the version number in the `ORACLE_HOME` variable. Again, mine is `12.2`, but yours might be something else. It is also common to set `TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/ora`, but I chose not to so that my `.ora` files are not in a version-dependent directory (such as `12.2`).

Edit `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf` to contain

```
/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/
```

Again, note the version number.

Finally, in `/etc/environment`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/"
CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
```

Once you've finished editing all these files, run

```
ldconfig
source /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
source /etc/environment
```

Hit `<Ctrl> + D` or type `exit` to revert to a regular user.

## Add as a Third-Party Driver

I don't know if this step is strictly necessary, but it works on my computer. If you open up SQL Developer, you can navigate to `Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> Third Party JDBC Drivers` and click `Add Entry`. Open to `/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64` and click on `lib`. It will hilight it, and then you can click `select` to add it to the list.

After this step you will need to close and re-open SQL Developer. Once you've done all that, *hopefully* you won't get any more errors.