# Move icon from Lubuntu 17.10 Menu

Tags: lubuntu

Following the answer below 
[How to install SQL Developer on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458554/how-to-install-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-14-04) 
I managed to get a proper working sql developer on an old machine with Lubuntu 17.10

What I'm trying to do now is to have the sqldeveloper in the application menu under programming.

I see it under Others.

Answer (score 1):

Go into `/usr/share/applications` and find the .desktop file for your application.  (It will probably be displayed as just an icon if you use a file manager to do this.  Part of mine looks like this, but the files are really called [something].desktop)

[image]

Copy it into `/home/[your-user-name]/.local/share/applications`

Open the .desktop file with your favorite text editor and look for the line starting with `Categories=`

Change this line so it reads `Categories=Development;` and save the file.

Your menu may refresh immediately; if it doesn't, open a terminal and type `lxpanelctl restart`